# Something wrong while calling a function in R

Tags: r

I wrote a R function to calculate the trace of a list of matrix. The way I create the list of matrix is:

```
matrix.list <- lapply(1:25, FUN=function(x) {matrix(1:x^2, nrow=x, ncol=x)})
```

The function to do the calculation is:

```
Cal_Trace <- function(matrix) {
    trace=0
    if (nrow(matrix) != ncol(matrix)) {
        return ("it's not a square matrix!")
    }
    for (i in 1:nrow(matrix)) {trace=trace+matrix[i,i]}
    trace
}
```

while I call the function in two ways, the results are different:

```
lapply(matrix.list, Cal_Trace)
```

This calling format works, however, while I do this way:

```
Cal_Trace(matrix.list)`
```

It pops up an error:

```
Error in if (nrow(matrix) != ncol(matrix)) { : the length of argument is zero.
```

I wonder why I must call the function using `lapply`, instead of using the simplest way.

Comment: `matrix.list` is a list of matrices. `lapply` lets you iterate through your list to access each `matrix`. By passing `matrix.list` directly to `Cal_Trace`, you are assuming a matrix, but it is a list. You need to modify your function to handle a list of matrices in that case.

Comment: In the future, use 4 white spaces to create code blocks that are more readable. ` ` notation is for in-line code.

Comment: Also, to compute the trace of a square matrix just do `sum(diag(mat))`. No need for a `for` loop. (And I don't find it a good idea to name an argument `matrix`, it's already an `R` function.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the function

```
    Call_Trace(matrix.list)
```

the input is a list, not a matrix, hence the error. List doesn't have nrow or ncol methods. When you use lapply, Call_Trace applies the function to each matrix in your matrix.list, which works as intended.